# Link of the oldest agent dies after first tick

Tags: netlogo

I am modelling vaccinations at general practices. After patients made an appointment with the assistants, the doctor will call them up if they are available. After one tick, the oldest patient shows a link (appointment) with its doctor. But after the next tick, the link disappears. This is only the case for the oldest patient. Can someone help me out?

The code is as follows:

```
breed [patients patient]
breed [doctors doctor]
breed [assistants assistant]
undirected-link-breed [appointments appointment]

globals [

  doctorslist
  assistantslist
  patientslist
patients-own [
  age
  ages
  vulnerability
  confidence ;in safety of vaccine
  immune?
  residence
  appointment?
  movementspeed
  willing-to-vaccinate
  my-assistant
  my-doctor
  omw?
  homepatch
]

doctors-own [

  vaccine-inventory
  openingtime
  vaccinations-on-planning-this-day
  vaccinations-remaining-this-day
  vaccinations-done-today
  available?
]
assistants-own [
  openingtime
  occupied?
  activityTime
  my-doctor

]

calls-own [
duration
]

to setup
  clear-all

  setup-doctors
  setup-assistants
  setup-patients
  setup-transporters
  setup-packers


  set central-vaccine-stock initial-central-vaccine-stock
  initTime

  ask patches [
    ifelse pxcor = -16 and pycor = 0 [set pcolor orange][ set pcolor white]]



  reset-ticks

end

to setup-doctors
  create-doctors number-doctors [
    let doctorlist (list doctor 0 doctor 1 doctor 2 doctor 3 doctor 4 doctor 5 doctor 6 doctor 7 doctor 8 doctor 9)
    set doctorslist doctorlist
    set shape "house"
    if item 0 doctorlist != nobody [ ask item 0 doctorlist [setxy 2 0 set doctorlist remove-item 0  doctorlist]]
    if item 0 doctorlist != nobody [ ask item 0 doctorlist [setxy 10 10 set doctorlist remove-item 0  doctorlist]]
    if item 0 doctorlist != nobody [ ask item 0 doctorlist [setxy -10 -10 set doctorlist remove-item 0 doctorlist]]
    if item 0 doctorlist != nobody [ ask item 0 doctorlist [setxy -5 5 set doctorlist remove-item 0  doctorlist]]
    if item 0 doctorlist != nobody [ ask item 0 doctorlist [setxy 11 -7 set doctorlist remove-item 0  doctorlist]]
    repeat (count doctors - 5) [if item 0 doctorlist != nobody [ ask item 0 doctorlist [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set doctorlist remove-item 0  doctorlist]]]



    set color green

    set vaccine-inventory 0
    set openingtime true
    set vaccinations-on-planning-this-day 0
    set vaccinations-done-today 0
    set available? true
  ]

end

end



to setup-patients
create-patients number-patients [
    set shape "person"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    let xy patch-here
    set homepatch xy
    set color black
    set age 1 + random 99
    set ages age
    set immune? false
    set appointment? false
    set movementspeed 0
    set omw? false

]
  set patientslist sort-on [(- age)] patients



end

to setup-assistants
  create-assistants (number-doctors * number-assistants-per-doctor)[
    let assistantlist (list assistant count doctors assistant (count doctors + 1) assistant (count doctors + 2)
                            assistant (count doctors + 3) assistant (count doctors + 4)
                            assistant (count doctors + 5) assistant (count doctors + 6)
                            assistant (count doctors + 7) assistant (count doctors + 8)
                            assistant (count doctors + 9) assistant (count doctors + 10)
                            assistant (count doctors + 11) assistant (count doctors + 12)
                            assistant (count doctors + 13) assistant (count doctors + 14)
                            assistant (count doctors + 15) assistant (count doctors + 16)
                            assistant (count doctors + 17) assistant (count doctors + 18)
                            assistant (count doctors + 19) assistant (count doctors + 20))
    let doctorlist doctorslist
    set assistantslist assistantlist
  set shape "person"
    repeat (count doctors)[
      if item 0 assistantlist != nobody [
        repeat number-assistants-per-doctor [
          ask item 0 assistantlist [ setxy [xcor] of item 0 doctorlist [ycor] of item 0 doctorlist
                                     set assistantlist remove-item 0 assistantlist ]]
                                     set doctorlist remove-item 0 doctorlist]]
  set color red
  set openingtime true
  set calling-speed calling-speed
    set occupied? false
    set my-doctor one-of doctors-here

]
end

to go
  repeat (count assistants + 1) [make-appointment] 
  go-to-doctor
  order-vaccines
  hang-up-phone
  call-up-patients
  vaccinate
  ;transport-vaccines

  updateTime

  tick

end

to make-appointment


    ask max-one-of patients [ages]  [
    if appointment? = false [

    let free-assistants assistants with [ occupied? = false]
    set my-assistant min-one-of free-assistants [distance myself]
    if my-assistant != nobody [set my-doctor [my-doctor] of my-assistant]


   if my-assistant != nobody [
        create-call-with my-assistant [hide-link]

      set appointment? true
      set color pink
       set ages 0

  ]]]

 ask assistants [
  ifelse count my-calls = 1 [
    set occupied? true][
      set occupied? false]
  ]


end
to call-up-patients

   let patientlist patientslist

  ask doctors [

    if CurHour = 0 and CurMinute = 0 [set vaccinations-on-planning-this-day 0
                                      set vaccinations-done-today 0
                                      ask appointments [die] ]
    if (vaccinations-on-planning-this-day + vaccinations-done-today) < injection-capacity [ set available? true]
  ]

   if length patientlist != 0 [ ask item 0 patientlist [
    ifelse appointment? = true and [available?] of my-doctor = true
    [
      create-appointment-with my-doctor set patientslist remove-item 0 patientlist ][ask item 1 patientlist [
    ifelse appointment? = true and [available?] of my-doctor = true
    [
          create-appointment-with my-doctor set patientslist remove-item 1 patientlist ][ask item 2 patientlist [
    if appointment? = true and [available?] of my-doctor = true
    [
              create-appointment-with my-doctor set patientslist remove-item 2 patientlist ] ]]]]]]; hier zit een fout. Als ik set patientslist verander in set patientlist maakt alleen de oudste agent een afspraak.
  ;patientlist is niet hetzelfde als patientSlist. soms maken patienten een appointment met een andere doctor dan my-doctor. appointment van de oudste patient gaat aan uit.

  ask doctors [if (count my-appointments + vaccinations-done-today = injection-capacity)  [
    set available? false]
    set vaccinations-on-planning-this-day count my-appointments]

 ask patients [if count my-appointments = 1 [
    set omw? true]]

end


to go-to-doctor
  ask patients [
    if omw? = true [
     if my-doctor != nobody [ face my-doctor let remaining-distance distance my-doctor
        ifelse remaining-distance >= 1 [fd 1][fd remaining-distance ]]]]

end
```

I included the relevant parts of the code. There is not asked to the oldest patient to die its appointment, but it does. Does someone have a solution for this?

One more question: in the call-up patients procedure the command for removing the first item of the patientlist is "set patientSlist", while patientlist (without an S) is the local list of patientSlist. If i remove the S, the command does not work anymore. Does someone know how i can fix this?

Comment: can you show only the relevant code? most likely that is whichever procedure has a `die` instruction for a link, and the procedure that calls it

Comment: I already found the mistake. It was due to the instruction of the `die` instruction when curhour and curminute are 0. I didn't realize that that was the case at the first tick. Thank you